# How to use OR with ng-pattern

Tags: angularjs

Here is my Input field where I am using ng-pattern

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" 
ng-pattern="/(^[A-z]+$) | (^[0-9]*$)/"
required="" ng-model="name"/>
```

Input from the user should be either a number or alphabets. How to use OR(|) operator with ng-pattern?

Following are valid inputs :

- 123  (All numbers)
- abc (All alphabets)

Following are invalid inputs :

- a1
- .tgh7

Comment: Just remove the white spaces around the `|`.

Comment: This worked, Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just combine your two current regex patterns into a single pattern:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="name"
       ng-pattern="/(^([A-z]+|[0-9]+)$)/"
       required="" ng-model="name" />
```

This approach might outperform what you currently have, because it requires evaluating only a single regex pattern, instead of two patterns.

Follow the link below for a demo of the regex:

## Regex101

Comment: Removing the whitespaces worked for me. Thank you for the reply :)